# React Loader Issue depends on directory?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've been playing with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-timeline and I have an issue.

If I want to overload the timeline class, I simply do

```
import React from 'react'
import Timeline from 'react-calendar-timeline';
export class MyTimeline extends Timeline {
     //Here I can override methods
}
export default MyTimeline;
```

This compiles, and works correctly.

However, if I want to make the import statement:

```
import Timeline from 'react-calendar-timeline/src/lib/Timeline';
```

(I will eventually also have to update the .../lib/Item/item.js file and therefore need to inherit timeline.js, and /lib/items/items.js to make sure that we load my overridden item.js file instead of that branch's file).

I get loader issues, and don't really understand why.

```
Module parse failed: PATH\node_modules\react-calendar-timeline\src\lib\Timeline.js Unexpected token (36:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| export default class ReactCalendarTimeline extends Component {
|   static propTypes = {
```

I don't understand this error because if I take everything from the react-calendar-timeline/src/lib directory inside of node_modules, and put it directly into my project, I can now inherit from the Timeline.js file (I know physically moving the directory out of node modules and into my project is bad practice).

So why is webpack able to compile the same code when it is in my actual project directory instead of node_modules?

My current webpack.config

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
        }
    },
    { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow babel to transform class properties using the `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` plugin. Link: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/